# Why do we need telegraf when using statsd

Tags: performance, monitoring, statsd, telegraf

I see the combination statsd + telegraf + influxdb used all the time.

- Statsd collects, aggregates and forwards metrics
- Telegraf aggregates and forwards metrics

Why not use just the statsd (without telegraf) to aggregate and forward metrics? What is the added benefit of including telegraf?

Comment: telegraf is a plugin based solution and has 4 concepts of distinct plugins. https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins (See plugins for inputs and output). Due to the capabilities telegraf provides (T under TICK stack), it's better to use a plugin based solution. Telegraf also collects metrics using it's core or available input plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The last update to Etsy's statsd project was in 2016. One advantage of using telegraf is that it is an active project. Since telegraf [has a Statsd plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/statsd), it's possible that you don't need both.

Comment: The statsd plugin doesn't replace statsd does it? Doesn't it just allow statsd to pipe information into telegraf? Maybe it does actually replace it...

Comment: Statsd latest commit was [on Aug 27, 2020](https://github.com/statsd/statsd/commit/9cf77d87855bcb69a8663135f59aa23825db9797). Just saying that is not _this_ old.

Comment: StatsD appears to be actively maintained in 2023